# Не могу понять почему не находит правильно дорогу для выхода из лабиринта

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сделать шахматную доску чтоб афишировать ходы "слона" я решил сделать в виде лабиринта, но он не хочет найти путь. В файле: 1-это преграда; 0 - это и есть путь.

Вот условия проблемы :

Считается шахматной доски размера nХn с препятствиями. Требуется для печати минимальное количество ходов, необходимых для перемещения сумасшедшего (слона), соблюдая правила игры в шахматы и избегая препятствий, из начального положения в конечное положение. Считается, что в начальное и конечное положение слона нет никаких препятствий.

Вот код :

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
int n,m,L[10][10],sol[10][10],nrsol=0,is,js;
int dx[]={-1,0,1,0},dy[]={0,1,0,-1};

void citire()
{
    int i,j;
    //читает фаил с дорогой
    ifstream f("C:\\Users\\nickk\\Desktop\\New folder\\labirint.txt");
    f>>n>>m>>is>>js;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
            f>>L[i][j];
}


void afisare()
{
    int i,j;
    nrsol++;
    cout<<"Solutia nr "<<nrsol<<endl;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
            cout<<setw(3)<<sol[i][j];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void traseu(int i, int j, int pas)
{
    int inou,jnou,k;
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
    {
        inou=i+dx[k];
        jnou=j+dy[k];
        if(inou>=1 && inou<=n && jnou>=1 && jnou<=m)
             if(L[inou][jnou]==0 && sol[inou][jnou]==0)
             {
                sol[inou][jnou]=pas;
                if(inou==1 || inou==n || jnou==1 || jnou==m)
                  afisare();
                 traseu(inou,jnou,pas+1);
                 sol[inou][jnou]=0;
             }
    }
}


int main()
{
    citire();
    sol[is][js]=1;
    traseu(is,js,2);
    cout<<nrsol;
}
```

Вот скрин файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что значит афишировать ходы "слона". Предсказывать?

Comment: Как нужно , ну да что то в этом вроде